# Unit test framework for Vala

Tags: c, unit-testing, vala

I am thinking of developing an application using Vala. I would like to write unit tests for my code - but I have not (as yet) found any **actively maintained** unit test frameworks for Vala (e.g. Valadate).

Could anyone recommend a unit testing framework for use with Vala?

As an aside, given the relative 'newness' of Vala, can Vala be considered production ready - are there any known enterprise apps out there developed in Vala?

Comment: Why is this tagged as 'c'?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a simple unit test facility already built into Vala: [`GLib.Test`](http://valadoc.org/#!api=glib-2.0/GLib.Test).

Unity, the user interface for the Ubuntu desktop, is partly written in Vala (the rest is C++.)

Comment: [Here](http://esite.ch/2012/06/26/writing-tests-for-vala/) you can find a useful post

Comment: The answer is correct, but it is kind of lack luster. Especially since the official documentation on how to use those unit tests is kind of sketchy :/